# Magento2 mobile product deatil page how to slide the page while holding down the product image

Tags: magento2

I mean:
When I browse the **product** on the **phone side**
Fingers slide to the product gallery, only left and right slide to switch pictures, can not slide up and down to switch the page location.
with magento 2.1.x

Comment: Do you mean the page can not be scrolled if you try to scroll in the image area?

Comment: Yes,Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the whole onMove(e) function in file lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js. If that does not work you can add the same in gallery.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onMove(e) {
            if ((e.touches && e.touches.length > 1)
                || (MS_POINTER && !e.isPrimary)
                || moveEventType !== e.type
                || !touchEnabledFLAG) {
                touchEnabledFLAG && onEnd();
                (options.onTouchEnd || noop)();
                return;
            }

            extendEvent(e);

            var xDiff = Math.abs(e._x - startEvent._x), // opt _x → _pageX
                yDiff = Math.abs(e._y - startEvent._y),
                xyDiff = xDiff - yDiff,
                xWin = (tail.go || tail.x || xyDiff >= 0) && !tail.noSwipe,
                yWin = xyDiff < 0;


            if (touchFLAG && !tail.checked) {
              if (touchEnabledFLAG = xWin) {
                stopEvent(e);
              }
            } else {
                stopEvent(e);
                (options.onMove || noop).call(el, e, {touch: touchFLAG});
            }

            if (!moved && Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDiff, 2) + Math.pow(yDiff, 2)) > tolerance) {
                moved = true;
            }

            tail.checked = tail.checked || xWin || yWin;
        }
</script>
```